# how to insert one to many relation in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

this is navigation schema

```
    Schema::create('navigations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

this is sub navigation schema

```
    Schema::create('sub_navigations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('nav_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('nav_id')->references('id')->on('navigations')->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

this is navigation model

```
public function subnavigations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Admin\Sub_navigation');
}
```

this is sub navigation model

```
public function navigation(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Admin\Navigation');
}
```

controller's code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //return $request->all();
    $sub_navigation = new Sub_navigation;

    $sub_navigation->name = $request->name;
    $sub_navigation->nav_id = $request->navigation[0];
    //return $sub_navigation;
    //$sub_navigation->save();
    $navigation = Navigation::find($request->navigation[0]);
    // $navigation->subnavigations()->save($sub_navigation);
    //return $navigation;
    $sub_navigation->navigation()->associate($navigation);
    $sub_navigation->save();






    return redirect()->back();

}
```

this is error message

> `` SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'navigation_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `sub_navigations` (`name`, `nav_id`, `navigation_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Philosophy, 2, 2, 2019-11-25 02:17:33, 2019-11-25 02:17:33)) ``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:
[One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

> Remember, Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column on the `Sub_navigation` model. By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it with `_id`. So, Eloquent will assume the foreign key on the `Sub_navigation` model is `navigation_id`. You can override the foreign key by passing additional argument to the `hasMany` method:

```
/**
 * Get the subnavigations for the navigation.
 */
public function subnavigations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Admin\Sub_navigation', 'nav_id');
}
```

[One To Many (Inverse)](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

> Eloquent will try to match the `navigation_id` from the `Sub_navigation` model to an id on the `Navigation` model. Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with a `_` followed by the name of the primary key column. However, if the foreign key on the `Sub_navigation` model is not `navigation_id`, you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the `belongsTo` method:

```
/**
 * Get the navigation that owns the sub_navigation.
 */
public function navigation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Admin\Navigation', 'nav_id');
}
```